# Globalization C#: Percentage data formatting:

Tags: c#, globalization

Does the way percentage data is formatted is also part of `CultureInfo`? By formatting, I mean, whether to display it as 47.3 or 0.473 etc.

My actual problem is that for DE language, I have to use 47.3% notation and for others 0.473, so I am looking that whether these things also depends upon culture just like the symbol used for decimal point.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You'll have to write code to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the way percentage data is formatted is also part of `CultureInfo`?

Yes, but not in the way you want. You can use the [`P` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString), but I don't think that would ever format it as 0.473:

> The percent ("P") format specifier multiplies a number by 100 and converts it to a string that represents a percentage. The precision specifier indicates the desired number of decimal places. If the precision specifier is omitted, the default numeric precision supplied by the current PercentDecimalDigits property is used.

So the culture affects the number of decimal digits, the decimal separator and probably the handling of numeric values, but I don't believe anything affects the "value is multiplied by 100" part.

Comment: Beat you by 31 second Jon, but I bet you still get 454353453 upvotes and the accepted answer, perks of being the local celeb and all ;)

Comment: @mattytommo: Well, I'd like to think I answered the question a bit more fully, in that the OP specifically asked about some cultures apparently displaying just the proportion without multiplying by 100...

Comment: Well, technically that quote paragraph is from the MSDN link I provided and your last sentence essentially paraphrases that paragraph. So realistically, they're essentially the same (short of me copying *all* of the MSDN content :)

Comment: @mattytommo: Oh the quoted paragraph is definitely from MSDN, and indeed from the same section we both linked to. But what I've highlighted is the difference between what the standard formatter provides and what the OP actually *wants*. You've just said to use that standard format - which *won't* achieve the desired result. Look at the OP's requirements - do you believe the code you've provided will actually satisfy those requirements? I don't - and that's the point of the extra text I've provided. I don't think our answers are essentially the same at all.

Comment: I believe you were probably right in the lack of information in my answer, now I've provided more information and a small code sample to illustrate the effects.

Answer (score 7):

You'd have to write code to do that, something like:

```
string.Format("Value: {0:P2}.", 0.473) // formats as 47.3 % (varies by culture)
```

It is the [`P` format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString) that governs the format based on the culture.

It is worth noting that the `P` format specifier will **multiply the number by 100** because it based on decimal notation (with 1 being 100%, 0.5 being 50%, etc.).

So the following using the `de-DE` culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

Console.WriteLine("1. " + string.Format("Value: {0:P2}.", 0.473));
Console.WriteLine("2. " + string.Format("Value: {0:P2}.", 47.3));
```

Will output:

> 1. 47.30%
> 2. 4,730.00%

Which is the same as what would be outputted for the English Culture `en-GB`.

Running the same code using theTurkish culture highlights the differences in format (as they use %23 instead of 23%).

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
```

Running the above code (printing the two lines used for the german culture above) will output:

> 1. %47.30
> 2. %4,730.00